# DatePicker Highlight Only One Weekday

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, calendar

Ok so, below is the code, I'm trying to adapt apple's code to show only 1 weekday (the weekday the app was launched) every week, right now I can nail down a span of x days, but I'm trying to get 1 day each week to appear and the rest to be blocked out:

```
let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 5, day: 1)
    let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 5, day: 12)
    return calendar.date(from:startComponents)!
        ...
        calendar.date(from:endComponents)!
}()

DatePicker("Date", selection: $date, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
                .labelsHidden()                      // dateRange called from in:
```

Any ideas? Kind of new to dates, it's heavy

Comment: `DatePicker` in SwiftUI can't do that. It might be possible with UIDatePicker wrapped in a UIRepresentable. Or you can simply use a `Picker` list of the respective dates, but then you'll loose DatePicker styling and behavior.

Comment: @ChrisR thanks for the response, i’ll reconsider my design